# Create Wavesplatform address address from seed

Tags: wavesplatform

I want to generate addresses in the code of my application and then make transactions from these addresses. To sign transactions - I need some waves on this accounts. But how can I get the address, knowing only it's seed?

Answer (score 1):

A first question would be to ask what progamming language are you using?
My favorite is [pywaves](https://github.com/PyWaves/PyWaves).

In pywaves it is as easy to create a address from your seed by executing following code:

```
myAddress = pw.Address(seed='put your seed here')
```

This library knows how to convert the seed into an address object. From there you can execute actions on the object. If you want to get your address back as a string you can use:

```
myAddress.address
```

There are also other library's like wavesJ or similar javascript/C++/.. library's, however I don't have a lot off experience with those.

Comment: That's great but what about other official libs? JS etc?

Comment: https://docs.wavesplatform.com/en/waves-api-and-sdk/client-libraries.html here is a overview from all librarys